# Contentul and Angular universal with a custom adapter

Tags: angular, contentful

I am trying to use [Contentful](https://www.contentful.com/) in my Angular Universal application but I would like to override their adapter with my own.

I have tried to do it like this:

```
private client = createClient({
  space: environment.space,
  accessToken: environment.cdaAccessToken,
  adapter: (config: any) => {
    config.adapter = null;
    //console.log(config);
    //console.log(config.headers);
    return this.http
      .request(config.method, `${config.baseURL}/${config.url}`, {
        headers: {
          Accept: config.headers['Accept'],
          Authorization: config.headers['Authorization'],
          'Content-Type': config.headers['Content-Type'],
          'X-Contentful-User-Agent':
            config.headers['X-Contentful-User-Agent'],
        },
        params: config.params,
      })
      .toPromise();
  },
});
```

which sort of works; I can see it is using my provider, but it keeps reporting an error when it does a request:

> Object.defineProperty called on non-object

I can see that it's trying to invoke `wrapEntryCollection` in the **contentful.js** file and is expecting `response.data` as a parameter. For me, when using my custom adapter, response.data is always undefined.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation I found that when not using my adapater, the response is like this:

```
{
    config: {},
    data: {},
}
```

but my response was just returning the data. So I updated my adaptor to this:

```
private client = createClient({
  space: environment.space,
  accessToken: environment.cdaAccessToken,
  adapter: (config: any) => {
    config.adapter = null;
    //console.log(config);
    console.log(config.headers);
    return this.http
      .request(config.method, `${config.baseURL}/${config.url}`, {
        headers: {
          Accept: config.headers['Accept'],
          Authorization: config.headers['Authorization'],
          'Content-Type': config.headers['Content-Type'],
          'X-Contentful-User-Agent':
            config.headers['X-Contentful-User-Agent'],
        },
        params: config.params,
      })
      .toPromise()
      .then((response: any) => {
        console.log(response);
        return { data: response };
      });
  },
});
```

and it worked